# When a ConcurrentBag is better than a List?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, parallel-collections

I am using a Parallel.Foreach for populating an external ConcurrentBag. I tried also to use a common List and everything works fine.

I have been lucky or I missed the special scope of ConcurrentBag?

Comment: How many cores/CPUs does your development machine have?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have been lucky; `Parallel.ForEach` to populate a List is not thread-safe, you will eventually run into problems.

According to MSDN, `List<T>` is not thread safe:

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> A List<T> can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified. Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an
>   enumeration contends with one or more write accesses, the only way to
>   ensure thread safety is to lock the collection during the entire
>   enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple
>   threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

ConcurrentBag is what you should use for this, which is thread-safe for multiple readers and writers.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `Parallel.ForEach` to populate a `List<T>` and everything is working just fine then you're simply getting lucky.  The `ForEach` method can and will run your code on multiple threads so any communication outside the `ForEach` must be with objects that can handle concurrent updates.  `List<T>` cannot but `ConcurrentBag<T>` can.

Answer (score 2):

ConcurrentBag is the correct answer, only in .NET 4.0 it is very slow. This has been fixed in .NET 4.5. See http://ayende.com/blog/156097/the-high-cost-of-concurrentbag-in-net-4-0

Both ConcurrentStack and ConcurrentQueue will also work in your situation...