# Usage of ConcurrentBag<T> vs list<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, task

Currently I was working on parallel threads in C#. So, I have confusion of using `ConcurrentBag<T>` and `List<T>`.

Here is my code:

```cs
public async Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<T>>> MethodA(SearchResults<Result> response)
{
     var a = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<DeviceAlertAlarm>>();
    
     var tasks = response.GetResults().Select(async result) =>
     {
            var b = new List <T>();
            // do something
            a["xxx"] = b;
            
     });
     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
     return a;
}
```

> For **var b = new List ();**

Is it mandatory  of `ConcurrentBag<T>` in multi-threading or can I use `List<T>` which is best way of writing the code with respective of performance.

Which one is better `Concurrentbag<T>` or `List<T>`  in the above part of code?

Comment: Better how? What do you want to do with the things in there?

Comment: If you were not sure how to abstract an question, please show us the concrete problem you have met.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thank you for quick response. i have edited the question could please check it once. // do something here means calling to db

Comment: The `List<T>` inside the lambda delegate won't be accessed concurrently so doesn't need to be a concurrent type

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ICollection<DeviceAlertAlarm>>` would suffice for this example.

Comment: Have you tried `new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<DeviceAlertAlarm>>();`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When a ConcurrentBag is better than a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193698/when-a-concurrentbag-is-better-than-a-list)

Comment: Hi prasanthi. I see you are getting some negative reactions to your posts. I can't comment on the content of your posts, but I notice your writing tends towards being a bit needy. Technical writing is an expectation here, so "please help me" and "thanks in advance" are best not added. Posts may be regarded as being a bit tatty or in need of improvement with this sort of chatroom stuff, and if readers find they do not like the post, the conversational material may encourage them to downvote. Please try to avoid adding it. Thanks!

Comment: Boilerplate advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your inner list is never used *concurrently* you also do not need to use a `ConcurrentBag<T>` here.

Commented your example a bit. From what I expect your code is doing I would take `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` in the `ConcurrentDictionary<string, IEnumerable<T>>`.

```cs
// IEnumerable, List, Collection ... is enough here.
public async Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, IEnumerable<T>>> MethodA(SearchResults<Result> response)
{
     var a = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IEnumerable<DeviceAlertAlarm>>();
    
     var tasks = response.GetResults().Select(async (result) =>
     {    
            //
            // This list just exists and is accessed in this 'task/thread/delegate'
            var b = new List<T>();
            //
            // do something ...
            //
            // The surrounding IDictionary as you have it here 
            // is used *concurrently* so this is enough to be thread-safe
            a["xxx"] = b;
            
     });
     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
     return a;
}
```